# Decode Json object by using JQuery is not working well

Tags: html, json

I used AJAX to get a Json object from a web method. 
  Most elements can be decoded well, except the "Content" element.

The following is the Json Object.

```
{"d":"\u003cNewDataSet\u003e\r\n  
        \u003cId\u003e13410\u003c/Id\u003e\r\n    
        \u003cContextId\u003ee055817c-9233-12d1-a559-ff03465875af\u003c/ContextId\u003e\r\n
        \u003cTimestamp\u003e2014-09-19T21:40:02.97-07:00\u003c/Timestamp\u003e\r\n   
        **\u003cContent\u003e\u0026lt;SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"\u0026gt;\u0026lt;SOAP-ENV:Header\u0026gt;\u0026lt;/SOAP-ENV:Envelope\u0026gt;\u003c/Content\u003e\r\n**    
    \u003c/NewDataSet\u003e"}
```

When I use  `$().html(Id)` or `$().html(ContextId)` or `$().html(Timestamp)`, it shows correct data content in the web page; however, using **`$().html(Content)` is showing nothing**....

If I just use **`alert(Content)`** function of jquery, it can show the correct format like

```
< SOAP=ENV:Envelop xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelop/......>......< /SOAP-ENV:Envelope >
```

I can't figure out why only "Content" element didn't act correctly like other elements...

Comment: You're trying to create a soap envelope as html so it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$().text(Content)` as this will HTML escape your content. Otherwise your `content` that contains tags will be interpeted as tags which are unknow to the browser and ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

var result;

result = jQuery.parseJSON(Content);

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to create a soap envelope as html so it won't work; that's not valid html. You can see it in an alert because you're asking for text. This would be valid Javascript:

```
var strSoapEnv = Content;
```